# What is the best practice for arranging Android apps with multi-screens and a fixed custom navigation bar?

Tags: java, android, oop, android-fragments, android-studio

I am making an app and want to make sure I am following good practices before I proceed further and potentially turn my app into a "big ball of mud" implementation.

So right now the general idea I have in my head is where you have a row of icons along the top representing the different pages you can click on. You click the button/icon and it takes you to that page.

So this icon-row along the top would be constant throughout most of the app. The only thing that would change would be the contents below that icon-row.

Is it considered acceptable practice to use fragments here? Use one main activity that has the icon-row at the top and then have the container below that "swap out" fragments based on the icon clicked? And then each page is really just a big fragment?

Does this make sense, am I following good practice? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If this is the wrong stackexchange: Which stackexchange is appropriate for "best practices" type questions?

Comment: Probably Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am making an app and want to make sure I am following good practices before I proceed further and potentially turn my app into a "big ball of mud" implementation.

If that happens, try a good brand of laundry detergent, at least if you are using Twitter Fabric.

> So right now the general idea I have in my head is where you have a row of icons along the top representing the different pages you can click on. You click the button/icon and it takes you to that page.

A typical implementation of that in mobile apps is to use tabs that contain your icons.

> Is it considered acceptable practice to use fragments here? Use one main activity that has the icon-row at the top and then have the container below that "swap out" fragments based on the icon clicked? And then each page is really just a big fragment?

Most modern tab implementations are based around using a `ViewPager` as the container for the tabs, so the user can swipe the content or tap on the tab to switch to different pages. `ViewPager` can work with plain views for its pages, but the stock `PagerAdapter` implementations use fragments.

Even if you elected to eschew tabs, using fragments for the pages (whether wrapped in a `ViewPager` or not) is reasonable.

The big thing to watch out for is memory consumption. Android devices do not have infinite RAM.<sup>[citation needed]</sup> You need to make sure that you have a modest number of fragments outstanding at any given point.

Comment: What do you consider a modest number (ballparked)? Is 5 considered crazy? 10? 50? 100? When is a good "proceed with caution" point?

Comment: @foshizzlin: It would depend upon what's in the fragment. Fragments can be cheap or crazy-expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the proper way to use the parent activity or fragment with this "icon-row". You can use the Toolbar+menu for example, if you want to preserve the Android look, use tabs+ViewPager or use custom view.

Then, in this activity/fragment you will have a layout that will work as a fragment container. In this layout you can replace the fragments dynamically using the FragmentManager of parent activity/fragment. Each of these pages is a separate fragment.

So yes, this is good/common practice.

You may read the how-to about replacing fragments [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)